# Azure ARM - Live swapping of LB backend pool

Tags: load-balancing, azure

I am currently investigating the feasibility of swapping the backend pool of an Azure load balancer, whilst not interrupting the experience for those requests coming into the load balancer.

The reason being is to create a blue/green deployment strategy, where we create a new availability set (VMSS potentially) and update the load balancers backend pool to point to the new availability set.

I'd love to hear if anyone has had some experiences doing something like this in Azure.

Answer (score 1):

Azure Load Balancer probe comes from [168.63.129.16](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-troubleshoot). If you create a firewall rule on the VM to deny access to the probe port from that IP it will knock the VM out of the pool so no future connections will be routed to that VM (until the firewall rule is disabled). Existing connections from users continue unharmed.

I haven't tried your approach and don't know whether it will work. But you asked for our experience so I thought I would share that with you. I found it a great way to take a VM offline gracefully for maintenance from within the VM. And I was happy I didn't have to configure Azure PowerShell on the VM and a service principal to accomplish it.

Answer (score 1):

> I am currently investigating the feasibility of swapping the backend
>   pool of an Azure load balancer, whilst not interrupting the experience
>   for those requests coming into the load balancer.

As far as I know, we **can't** live swapping of LB backend pool and  not interrupt those requests.

As a workaround, we can use powershell to upgrade Azure Vmss. 
Here is the PowerShell script about update Azure Vmss instance (**it does an update one VM instance at a time**):

```
$rgname = "vmss"
$vmssname = "vmss"
$newURI = "imageurl"
$instanceid = "1"
$vmss = Get-AzureRmVmss -ResourceGroupName $rgname -VMScaleSetName $vmssname
$vmss.virtualMachineProfile.storageProfile.osDisk.image.uri= $newURI
Update-AzureRmVmss -ResourceGroupName $rgname -Name $vmssname -VirtualMachineScaleSet $vmss
Update-AzureRmVmssInstance -ResourceGroupName $rgname -VMScaleSetName $vmssname -InstanceId $instanceId
```

Here a blog about upgrade an Azure VM Scale Set **without shutting it down**, please refer to this [link](https://msftstack.wordpress.com/2016/05/17/how-to-upgrade-an-azure-vm-scale-set-without-shutting-it-down/).